# how to get live view of esp32cam at remote sever using ssh tunneling?

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, esp32, iot

I have found many projects involving esp32cam, but in all projects video is being seen on local server only.For its of no use.As for a home security project user can view the video at remote location like MI robotic camera.

Also i do not want any port forwarding or tunneling service from a third party like www.nabto.com, www.ngrok.com etc.

Comment: You will need something local to the ESP32CAM that can do the SSH tunnelling. Maybe a Raspberry Pi. Everything else is just networking and routing and port forwarding. Nothing about that affects the ESP32 in any way.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous there's an attempt to turn an ESP32 into an SSH server [here](https://github.com/hopkinskong/esp32-ssh-server), though you'd probably have to implement a whole lot more to do port forwarding.

Comment: did you post this duplicate? ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495797/how-can-i-make-a-project-in-which-using-esp32cam-i-can-see-live-video-at-remote